# CodeIgniter pages

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I've started dealing with CI just a couple of days ago, so I'm pretty much new to all this. I need to connect CI View with another common (normal) PHP file or HTML file. Can this be done in any way? For example

Comment: read the codeigniter user guide... http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/ . it will help you understand codeigniter better: for views: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your normal php file : normal.php (place this file in view section)

Then all you need to do is create a controller that extends CI_Controller, and assign it to load that normal.php

```
Class Normal extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
     $this->load->view('normal');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your normal php file is just a view file u can use

```
$this->load->view('your_file',$array_of_any_data_you want_to_pass_in_your_view);
```

however to include any php file you could simply use  include

```
<?php include 'my_php_file.php';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

of course you can.

- First, you need to create controller file in controllers folder under application directory, eg. application/controllers/frontpage.php and add this:

  > ```
  > Class Frontpage extends CI_Controller{
  > public function test_view() {
  >          $this->load->view('layouts');
  > }
  > ```
- and View part, you can put your *all common HTML layout files* on your views directory. eg application/views/layouts.php, application/views/style.css, etc.
- Then you need to change your css url ref base on your application url.

you can use `base_url()` function. eg:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/views/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But, better if you make styles directory and place all of your css files right there. 
Finally you can access it from localhost/yourapp/index.php/test_view

hopefully help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the lifecycle of a request. So let's say you want to serve a HTML view named about.php (which contains HTML code and a php variable named $app_version printed somewhere).

First you create the controller at application/controllers folder. For example application.php

```
class Application extends CI_Controller {

}
```

Then your create a method for your controller

```
class Application extends CI_Controller {
    public function about_handle() {
        //calculate and set any data you wish to pass in your view
        $this->data['php_version'] = '1.0';

        //then load the view
        $this->load->view('about', $data); //supposing there is a file named about.php in your application/views directory
}
```

And don't forget to create a route in your application/config/routes.php file

```
$route['about'] = 'application/about_handle';
```

Your view could be something like this

```
<h1>About this application</h1>
<h2>Current version <?= $php_version ?></h2>
```

Now on every request at `http://website.ex/about` or `http://website.ex/index.php/about` (if you haven't disabled "index.php" CIgniter's default) you will be serving the about.php view